# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Essa exceção acontece quando o alguns testes rodam no bamboo. O mais estranho é quando rodo localmente funciona e são testes aleatórios que quebram. Alguém já passou por isso?

A exception é essa:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration or timeout: 30.11 seconds Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40' System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-52-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_72' Session ID: 126f178d-2ac6-4c4f-a939-09e21052c04f Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=34.0}]
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 30.11 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-52-virtual', java.version: '1.7.0_72'
Session ID: 126f178d-2ac6-4c4f-a939-09e21052c04f
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=34.0}]
(48 more lines...)
```

Esse é o exemplo de um dos códigos em que esse problema ocorre:

```
String name;
String key;

@Before
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {

    driver.findElement(By.id("menu_topMenu.maintenance")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("menu_topMenu.route")).click();
}

@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    AddRoute addRoute = new AddRoute(driver);
    addRoute.add();
    name = addRoute.getName();
    key = addRoute.getKey();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_btn_novo")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_key > input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys(key);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_description > input[type=\"text\"]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_description > input[type=\"text\"]")).sendKeys(name);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_organization > div.lookUpHitArea")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#MonetUIFieldsLookupGridContainer_organization > div.slick-pane.slick-pane-top.slick-pane-left > div.slick-viewport.slick-viewport-top.slick-viewport-left > div > div:nth-child(2) > div.slick-cell.l0.r0.cell-row")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_plannedCost > input")).sendKeys("10000");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_origin > div.lookUpHitArea")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#MonetUIFieldsLookupGridContainer_location > div.slick-pane.slick-pane-top.slick-pane-left > div.slick-viewport.slick-viewport-top.slick-viewport-left > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.slick-cell.l1.r1.cell-row.selected")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_lastStopIsDestination > input")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector
            ("#Route_btn_save_and_close")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    assertTrue("Rota existente nao validada corretamente",
            isDisplayedByCssSelector(driver, "#form_and_grid > div > div.monetInlineAlerContainer > div"));
}
```

}

Comment: Olá, Poderia por favor colocar o código fonte?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa, coloquei um exemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em minhas experiências com Selenium também obtive erros aleatórios, inclusive com a exceção `ElementNotVisibleException`.

Em geral isso era devido à forma como o Web Driver interage com o navegador, lembrando que nas versões atuais a API do Selenium na verdade executa sobre um Driver específico do navegador (`FirefoxDriver`, neste caso).

O Web Driver tenta simular as ações de um usuário, porém quase sempre há diferenças em relação ao uso real, seja por questões de posicionamento de elementos que são calculados incorretamente ou pela diferença de *timing* da digitação ou movimentos do mouse.

Um caso específico que me lembro ocorreu em um menu com vários subníveis. Enquanto um usuário real conseguia navegar sem problemas pelo menu, os eventos gerados pelo WebDriver não conseguiam afetar corretamente os submenus porque o Selenium calculava incorretamente a posição dos itens.

Em casos assim, a solução encontrada foi substituir chamadas nativas à API do Selenium por comandos JavaScript que executavam as ações desejadas.

Comment: Não sei se está diretamente relacionado a movimentos de mouse...Pode dar uma olhada no código que adicionei?

Comment: @SandyMaciel A questão do movimento do mouse foi só um exemplo. Na verdade, os problemas são relacionados diretamente a falha no cálculo de posicionamento de elementos ou "pais" do elemento que são possuem estilos CSS que afetam suas posições, ou ainda a eventos JavaScript que ocultar/exibem ou criam elementos na tela. Vi que tem alguns *sleeps* no seu código. Isso serve para aguardar por algum evento?

Comment: Sim, é aguardando eventos aparecerem elementos na tela... por algum motivo não consigo com que os wait's funcionem... dicas?

Comment: @SandyMaciel Então o problema pode ocorrer em casos onde o Selenium tenta interagir com o elemento, mas este ainda não está num estado visível e pronto para uso. A dica seria aguardar por uma condição que confirmasse a conclusão dos tais eventos. Nem sempre isso é fácil, às vezes sendo necessário colocar alguma flag dentro do próprio sistema para isso. Quando há requisições Ajax sendo feitas pelo sistema, por exemplo através da função `$.ajax` do jQuery, é possível inspecionar a fila de requisições. No caso de transições ou animações, daria para olhar algum atributo para ver já finalizou.

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema é devido ao elemento não estar carregado ainda, o Selenium é muito rápido e as vezes o comando passa pela tela sem a mesma estar totalmente renderizada. Em testes locais, o carregamento costumam ser mais rápidos.

Tente usar este código:

```
public static void waitForPageToLoad(WebDriver driver) {          

  while( !((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete") ){
     try{
         Thread.sleep(500) ;
     } 
     catch (InterruptedException e) { 
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }        
    try {
         Thread.sleep(2000); 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) { 
       e.printStackTrace();
  }        
}
```

Ou simplesmente o comando abaixo para forçar uma espera na execução do Selenium, onde é informando o tempo em milisegundos que a thread irá esperar até que o elemento carregue.

```
Thread.sleep(500);
```

Comment: sempre uso Thread.sleep() mas ainda isso ocorre... e sei que thread.sleep() não é a melhor opção...